# HDMI sound option disappeared after upgrade of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, hdmi

After an automatic system upgrade of Ubuntu 22.04 the HDMI sound option disappeared leaving only spdif as an option for digital sound. As a result, I no longer have sound. I am using an amd rx580 video card. The same thing happened on my Windows 10 machine but it was relatively easy to restore by reinstalling the driver for the  video card. how do I accomplish the same thing in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to remove/re-install the standard drivers but as a possible alternative you could try using kisak-mesa [https://launchpad.net/~kisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa) or oibaf [https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) drivers to see if either resolves the issue.  Both are common driver packages.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my kernel to "5.19.0-32-generic" in grub's advanced options and both hdmi audio and displayport worked again.

Comment: It would be a good idea to have a complete answer. That would include how to change the kernel. Not everyone that reads this may have that knowledge.